# Firefox spellcheck settings keep changing

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, language, spell-check

The spell-check language setting on Firefox keeps changing to en_CA rather than the default of en_US. I change it back but it invariably flips... maybe in a few hours, maybe a few days. (It's hard to tell exactly) Nothing else on my system is Canadian, I don't know where it gets the idea.

At some point I suspected the profile: the wrong setting was in the profile but the profile was getting corrupted somehow so my changes weren't being saved. I started a new session, changed the settings, and closed the browser down to let it save the profile correctly. On restarting I was happy to see that it was correctly using US English, but then saw it flip back to Canadian.

My system is Ubuntu 12.08 with Firefox 18.

Comment: Ensure that the [en-US package](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all/) is installed, and that an [en-US dictionary](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/united-states-english-spellche/) is installed instead of an [en-CA one](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/canadian-english-dictionary/).

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Great find! I don't know if it counts as a duplicate or not, bring 3 years older, but definitely looks relevant.